# String to number in neo4j/cypher

Tags: string, neo4j, cypher, database, nosql

On a neo4j database, I have severals nodes that have a property in strings and I would like to convert them in numbers so I can order them properly in my queries in Cypher.

I don't mind adding a new property.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using tofloat() works perfectly.

Comment: `toInt()` is the other one.

Comment: Check this function- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger